# We made every living thing from water. Are Jinns "living" things?

Tags: quran, creation, jinn, contradiction

The Qur'an says:

> And that We have made every living thing out of water [[21:30](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.wahiduddin/21:30)]

Aren't jinn *living things*? What are they made of? Isn't it a contradiction with the the following verse?

> and the jinn We had created before from flaming fire. [[15:27](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.wahiduddin/15:27)]

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. TO learn more about our site and model I recommend you to take the 2min. [tour] and check our [help].

Comment: Here was an old answer now it disappears..but why I want that ans again..Thanks

Answer (score 9):

No,we already know that angels are made up of light and jinns are made up of fire.
The word 'everything' is according to the context of that verse. In that verse Arabic word for 'everything' used is 'kulla'. 
For example:
Suppose you little brother is eating chips and you asked that you wanted to eat some.
Then he said I ate everything and nothing is left.
Here it does not means that he ate everything in the world but here everything is used for that context only(for chips).
Hope you got my point..

Comment: [46:25](https://quran.com/46/25) and [27:23](https://quran.com/27/23) are some examples.

Answer (score 5):

I can't help but point out that water is literally produced from fire:

> Flames consist primarily of carbon dioxide, **water vapor**, oxygen and nitrogen. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire))

E.g. for methane combustion, we have the following chemical reaction:

[image: Combustion of methane]

(Image source: [Wikimedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Combustion_reaction_of_methane.jpg))

But I don't think this is the way it's intended to be interpreted.  The Qur'an also says:

> And We did certainly create man out of clay from an altered black mud. -- [Qur'an 15:26](https://quran.com/15:26)

Clearly this does not mean that man is some kind of clay monster.  It seems reasonable to interpret [Qur'an 15:27](https://quran.com/15:27) in the same spirit.

We don't view man being made out of clay as conflicting with the notion of man being made out of water.  They mean different things.

Comment: Angles are made from light? Does it include H2O aswell?

Answer (score 0):

Bismilah 
It’s very good question.  Jinns are made of smokes flames and humans/man out of mud.  Impurities in the fire makes the smoke.  So in another word Jinns are purest fire.  As we know black or dark mud represents fertility and excellent soil in the world of growing crops.  Almost similar concept is the creation of men.

V21.30 allah also tells as about the Big Bang and how he created every living thing out of water.  Don’t get confused dark mud has to contain or be in water to stay in it’s mudy state, so no contradiction there.  Then allah gave the pure fire and the mud a life or ordered to be and it was.

These states of originality is where we come from, but it’s not a state we are in right now. Let me explain a bit more.  If I make a car out of metal I collected from the earth and the say I created this car out of the sand and soil would you then say no. It’s made out of metal and other materials?  Or.  Why are we not still a sperm or in state of Leach like creature?  Because we have an origin doesn’t mean we should remain that state.
And for more clarity.  We all have in our body everything that is in the mud including precious metals. Like gold,platinum,iron,silver.  And we know very well that these metals came down from space or was forged in conditions far greater then the ones we see in our world.  Hence the saying we made of the same stuff as the starts.(star dust)

Do your self a favor read the Quran with sincerity and open mindedness.  I’m sure you don’t read books with preconceptions and judging mind.  Don’t be afraid.  And may Allah guide us all.

Answer (score 0):

We have made every living thing from water
( Quran surah ambiya 21, ayat 30 )

We have created jinn from flaming fire
( Quran surah hijr 15, ayat 27 )

Off course Jinns are also living thing made from flaming fire and scientifically flaming fire contain water vapour H2O in the form of gas ( check on wikipedia )

[https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire#:~:text=Flames%20consist%20primarily%20of%20carbon,fire's%20intensity%20will%20be%20different](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire#:%7E:text=Flames%20consist%20primarily%20of%20carbon,fire%27s%20intensity%20will%20be%20different).

No mistake and contradiction in quran

Answer (score 0):

May Allah forgive me if I'm incorrect about any of this but one thing I've heard from a well educated Sheikh that stood out to me on his explanation of this topic is.

Allah created WATER which gave off gasses that became heavenly bodies which came together by Allah's command to form planets. From those planets different elements formed. So for example a heavenly body that was formed became a sun and gave off an intense FIRE. This is what Allah created the Jinn from. That sun also gives off a bright LIGHT this is what Allah created the Angels from. Then perhaps a part of the sun broke off and cooled down turning into ice. The ice then over time melted into the oceans we have and grew life on Earth from which MANKIND was created by Allah from.

So this possibly shows how all living things r created by Allah from water as stated n Qur'an.

Answer (score 0):

Qur'an 21:30
Have those who disbelieved not considered that the heavens and the earth were a joined entity, and We separated them and made from water every living thing? Then will they not believe?

The key word is AND:

"and We separated them and made from water every living thing? Then will they not believe?"

Meaning after the heavens and Earth were split, every living thing on Earth was made from water, which is of course, scientific fact.

Answer (score 0):

Jinns are a maklooq(creation) of Allah Subhan Wa Ta'ala. Allah Subhan Wa Ta'ala made them out of fire, so their bodies are made out of fire. Believing in Jinns is required to be a Muslim. We normal people cant see them but High Ranking Taqwa People can see them i.e. Prophets, Saints. Jinns used to work for Prophet Suleman Aliessalam. We humans have 1 kid at a time, these Jinns have 9 at a time. Just like how there are non muslims and muslim humans, there are also non muslim and muslim Jinns. They eat and drink too, etc. We humans are made out of water but Jinn are made out of Fire

Answer (score -1):

And that We have made every living thing out of water [21:30]

These ayatin or verses were before existence of Jinn and Mankind, water flow to give life to every living things on the land during those Earliest periods.

and the jinn We had created before from flaming fire. [15:27]

An specified term of what were the Jinn made of, and nothing to do with the water stated of sura 21 verse 30, because the verse do not describe things that happen on the future but more on the you called it the modern word earth (actual ancient name: land which word 'earth' was been created after Revelation of Quran, that not from the Book) and heaven (actual ancient describe heaven): sky, region, space, zone, dominion, realm or place that not part of the land). If we use the Modern Man Made translation into English or to any language AFTER revelation of Quran for translation, surely be contradicted! Suggest to use the ancient translation English during and before the Revelation of Quran.

Summary; Living things before Jinn and Mankind indeed is make sense and the verse do not refer to future creations where it indicated more on the One joined land( earth) and the region(sky) development of earliest creations.

Answer (score -1):

I am not an expert in Arabic, but I have discussed this question with a scholar and according to him, the answer is following.
The confusion you raised is created due to reading only the translation and not the original Arabic text. Although a translation of any text helps to understand the general meaning, but can never exchange the true meaning and tone of the original content of any language. The same went here in this case. 
For the verse [21:30](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.wahiduddin/21:30), that is

> And that We have made every living thing out of water

used Arabic word **جعلنا** which has root word as **[جعل](https://en.bab.la/dictionary/arabic-english/%D8%AC%D8%B9%D9%84)**. Its [meanings](https://en.bab.la/dictionary/arabic-english/%D8%AC%D8%B9%D9%84) also include ‘to cause’, ‘to bring about’. The whole verse means that Allah has caused every living thing to depend on water. In other words, He has made continuity of every life hooked with some form of water.
In the other verse, that is for [15:27](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.wahiduddin/15:27) the translation reads as

> ...and the jinn We had created before from flaming fire.

Here Quran used word **خَلَقۡنٰهُ** for which the root word is **[خلق](https://en.bab.la/dictionary/arabic-english/%D8%AE%D9%84%D9%82)**. This [means](https://en.bab.la/dictionary/arabic-english/%D8%AE%D9%84%D9%82) “to create” or “to make”. Here, Allah is talking about the material of creation. Similarly, just one verse before it, i.e., at [15:26](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.wahiduddin/15:26), Allah discussed the material of the creation of man, which is clay.

> We created man out of dry clay, from molded mud

So, reading all these verses with their correct meanings known does not create any confusion. Collectively reading all these verses enables us to conclude that Allah created Jinns from the fire, human from clay, and made all His living creations dependent on water.  Now, as humans, we know that our life is dependent on water. Since we have never observed or perceive through our senses the living style of Jinns, therefore we do not understand how their life is dependent on water. But since the Holy Quran said this, we believe that what is said in it is like it is said.

MaShaAllah! Very good question. This shows that you are reading the Holy Quran with thinking. May Allah makes this a source of guidance for you, me, and everyone else who is reading it